# Can memory span be increased with training?

Tags: working-memory, short-term-memory

It is known that the average person can only hold 7 ± 2 items in their short term memory.

Can this number be increased with training **without** the use of mnemonics (for example the major system or the method of loci)? What is the consensus of possible improvements of memory span (or digit span) by training?

I only found [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0006899315000487), whose results

> ... support that working memory is limited by a fixed number of items.

Comment: Welcome. Does [this post](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/can-working-memory-actually-be-improved?rq=1) answer your question? It seems a dupe question.